# How to fix eror base 10 when emty or not integer input in loop

Tags: python-3.x

I'm creating simple multiplication program and i stuck at empty and non integer input

I tried while loop in loop and if/else but because the input is coming first it shows the error and breaks the program

```
while g < 20 :
    variable_1 =  random.randint (0,20)
    variable_2 = random.randint (0,9)
    answer = variable_1 * variable_2
    querystr = int(input("str(variable_1)+" x "+str(variable_2)+" = "))
```

program works fine with multiplication for any integer input if answer is correct or incorrect. problem is that should discard empty input and when entered a letter should be terminate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to first get the data from the user without casting it to an integer, then test the input to decide what to do.

The following example will wait until an input will be entered:

```
querystr = ''
while not querystr:
    querystr = input('What do you have to say?')
```

Now, if you want to break the loop if a letter is entered (when you expect only integers) you can try something like that:

```
import string
expected_int = ''
while not expected_int:
    try:
        expected_int = input('Insert an integer or a letter to exist:')
        if no expected_int:
            continue
        if expected_int in string.ascii_letters:
            break
        expected_int = int(expected_int)
    except:
        pass
```